# Akka stream from ftp, line by line

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I'm trying to read file from ftp server using alpakka and scala streams.
The type I get from the `Ftp.fromPath(...)` is `Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]]`. I would want to read the file line by line(it's a CSV file), but I don know how.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Can you show a little more code than that ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a standard way to split a `Source[ByteString, _]` by lines, called [`Framing.delimiter`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/current/index.html#akka.stream.scaladsl.Framing$@delimiter(delimiter:akka.util.ByteString,maximumFrameLength:Int,allowTruncation:Boolean):akka.stream.scaladsl.Flow[akka.util.ByteString,akka.util.ByteString,akka.NotUsed]). It can be used like this:

```
val source: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = Ftp.fromPath(...)

val splitter = Framing.delimiter(
  ByteString("\n"),
  maximumFrameLength = 1024,
  allowTruncation = true
)

val result: Source[ByteString, Future[IOResult]] = source.via(splitter)
```

The `maximumFrameLength` parameter determines the maximum length of a line; you can set it to `Int.MaxValue` to get an essentially unlimited line length (although it may be dangerous if your CSV lines are very long), and `allowTruncation` is set to `true` to allow the case when there is no new line at the end of your CSV file.

The `result` source, when materialized, will produce `ByteString`s corresponding to each line, without the newline character in them. If you expect your files to contain Windows line separators ("\r\n"), then you'll need to trim these strings manually.